# How to set mod_proxy to serve some files while others to be served by apache

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, tomcat5.5

I have enabled mod proxy to serve my jsp and servlets and it seem to work fine. So if i hit localhost, it takes request to tomcat and executes it. What is want is that servlets and jsp are forwarded to tomcat while php is handled by apache. Both JSP/Servlets and PHP files are in the same folder and I need to make a call from JSP?Servlet to PHP or may be vice versa as well. Now the problem is that PHP is also forwarded to tomcat it seems if I use following pattern -

```
ProxyPass /auto http://serv.corp.com:8080/auto/
```

All JSP/Servlets and PHP files are inside auto folder which is in webapps folder.

Kindly help me to route static content i.e. PHP to apache.

Answer (score 2):

To server static content by Apache and remain files by appserver (jboss in my case)..

**`httpd.conf` of Apache should look as:**--

```
DocumentRoot   /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

ProxyPass   /   !

ProxyPass   /  https://www.example.com:8443/

ProxyPassReverse  /  https://www.example.com:8443/
```

here for example `/logo.gif` will be served directly by
Apache from the `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/logo.gif file`.

And everything else will be served by appserver.

Hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [ProxyPassMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) rather than ProxyPass. Something like (untested)

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ !
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I understand that it will route my matched url from apache to tomcat. Now if I am in any servlet and i give <a href="\autoproj\abc.php">..where autoproj is my project directory under webapps where i have classes for jsp/servlets stored.....then it redirects via tomcat only. I want it to go through apache as its php. If I give full url like <a href="http:\\mymachine:82\autoproj\abc.php"> where 82 is the port for apache, then it works fine and gets handled by apache. Hence, was just wondering if there is way to let tomcat know that its not his piece but apache's.